# getter setter textfields JAVA GUI

Tags: c#, java

Hi what is JAVA equivalent to this peace of code written in C#
class 1 :

```
  public string Password
     {
         get { return password; }
         set { password = value; }
     }
```

class 2 :

```
        try
        {

            UserEntity user = new UserEntity();

            user.Password = textBoxPassword.Text;
            user.InsertUser();
            MessageBox.Show("User is registred");

        }
```

in java I wrote this : 
class 1 :

```
 protected int password ;


    public int getPassword(){
        return password;

    }

    public void setPassword(int password){
        this.password=password;
    }
```

class2 :

```
 LoginEntity login = new LoginEntity();
      login.getPassword() = pwdTextBox.getText();// here ERROR : required variable , found value
```

Comment: You're comparing `string Password` with `int password`... You could replace `login.getPassword() = ...` with `login.password = ...` to access the field directly. It would be better to set `password` to a `public` field in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In neither C# nor in Java can you have a method call on the left side of an assignment. So this:

```
login.getPassword() = pwdTextBox.getText();
```

is not valid in either Java or C#

Perhaps you want

```
login.setPassword(pwdTextBox.getText());
```

Though you really should avoid using Strings for passwords as they can be easily sniffed making your password protection poor.

Comment: ok you are right but C# code is working 100% , i don't know how to do same thing in java... some idea ?

Comment: `object.function() = value` could never work, nor in c#, nor in java. Left side is function and right side is object. You can't set value of call.

Comment: @user2026573 - If you say that it's working, then you're mistaken.  **C# can't do that.**  Are you sure that the code you're looking at is actually the working version?